# Issue in relative layout with scrollview

Tags: android

Please review the following GUI code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/frameLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:text="Continue" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_marginRight="22dp"></Button>

     <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="500px"
       android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
       >

            <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_height="426dp">
           <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/editText1" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginTop="32dp" android:text="@string/dealerNoString" android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
            <EditText android:layout_width="150dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2" android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"></EditText>

<EditText android:layout_width="150dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/editText2" android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"></EditText>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/DealerString" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginTop="43dp"></TextView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/textView3"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/orderString" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_below="@+id/editText2" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginTop="32dp"></TextView>
        <EditText android:layout_width="150dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/editText3" android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2">
        </EditText>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView4" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:textStyle="bold" android:text="@string/addressString"></TextView>
        <EditText android:layout_width="150dip" android:id="@+id/editText4" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"></EditText>
        <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/editText5" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/editText4" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText4" android:layout_marginLeft="23dp" android:layout_marginTop="26dp">
            <requestFocus></requestFocus>
        </EditText>



     </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>   
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have placed fours text edits smoothly when when trying to place fifth it automatically moves to the top of layout.I tried for many times .Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check set the **android:layout_marginTop** property of that 5th layout element?